# unable to use mapPoint (SUMMER package) in R

Tags: r, spatial, mappoint

While using the `mapPoints` function in R, I am facing an error(PFA).

```
loc <- readOGR("G:/Mphil Dissertation/Data/Shape File/IAGE71FL/IAGE71FL.shp", verbose = FALSE)
loc.dat <- data.frame(cluster = loc$DHSCLUST, long = loc$LONGNUM, lat = loc$LATNUM)

gps <- mapPoints(loc.dat, geo= geo, long = "long", lat = "lat", names = c("REGNAME"))
```

> Error in `[.data.frame`(new, , names, drop = FALSE) :    undefined
>   columns selected

Comment: Look at the output of `str (loc)` and `str (loc.dat)`. Try adding REGNAME to `loc.dat`

Comment: It's still showing the same error.

Comment: Edit your question and include the output of `str (loc.dat)`, and your new commands.